# How to download wine on window 10 pc and install on Ubuntu PC

Tags: wine

Basically I have a WNA 3100 USB wireless adapter but there are no drivers for it on Ubuntu. I read online I need to download and install wine in order to use the part.

How can I download wine on my windows 10 pc? I was going to put the files on a flash drive and put the flash drive into the Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Installing wine is not going to fix your wireless adapter, can you point out where you read this and we can try and interpret it?

Comment: This is what you need to do: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020&highlight=WNA3100 Instead of "apt-get" download all the DEBs from the packages site, copy them to Ubuntu and then use dpkg to install them. Where they say "wine to extract the files" you can do this in Windows. Chili555 does not have windows ;-)

Comment: @thomasrutter Here's the link: http://faq.apollo3.com/ljames/ubuntu/networksupport/

Comment: @Rinzwind I found my other wireless adaptor that works with linux. I didn't think that wine would let me install the drivers appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The instructions on that page are for using NDISwrapper, which is a legitimate way to get Windows wireless drivers working on Linux.  Wine is not required for NDISwrapper, but in the case of that article, they are using Wine to help extract the files from the Windows installer.

Comment: Get a different wireless adapter that works on Linux!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because installing Windows drivers in WINE won't get you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download wine on your Windows 10 PC, and wine will not help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think windows drivers would work on linux.

Comment: You can download dpkg packages on another PC.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you linked to describe using NDISwrapper to run your wireless device from the Windows drivers.  This is a legitimate way to get some wireless devices running on Linux, but if you can find a native Linux driver it's a better experience.

Wine is never needed to use NDISwrapper or to use any driver, but in the case of the instructions you linked to, Wine is being used just to extract a file from the installer .exe.

Do note that those instructions are old so may be out of date and/or there may be better solutions since that I'm not aware of.

You can download Ubuntu packages from another PC and transfer them, but it's an annoying and difficult process.  You go to packages.ubuntu.com, find the right package for the right version of Ubuntu, and download the .deb file.

For example:

> http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/wine/download

However the above link assumes you're using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) AMD64.

Once you have copied the .deb file to your Ubuntu PC you install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Where packagename.deb is the name of the file.

Installing packages like this is a pain because if it turns out that a package requires another package, you have to go and get those packages too, and so on.

In this case you'll need to get packages for wine, wine1.6, wine1.6-amd64, wine1.6-i386 and in turn those have a bunch more dependencies such as audio and video decoders.

If at all possible, it may be easier to run the setup.exe on your Windows PC instead and try and extract the resulting files from there.